# How to verify mock method parameter of class type contains a value using mockito for junit

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have a service unit test, where I need to mock a Dao but also i need to verify the method parameter of class type property **studyRefActive**  contains a value **"Y"**

RegDao class:

```
public class RegDao {
----
----
public void save(Study study){
  //DB call to insert 
}

}
```

RegService class:

```
public class RegService {

private RegDao  regDao;
 //Inject dao here 

  public void saveStudy(Study study){
    
     //some data assignements
    study.setStudyRefActive("Y");
    regDao.save(study);

   }


}
```

my unit test:

```
RegDao mockRegDao = mock(RegDao.class);
RegService regService = new RegService(mockRegDao);
Study study = new Study();
Mockito.doNothing.when(mockRegDao).saveStudy(any(Study.class));
 regService.saveData(study)
```

so my question is how can i validate the Study DTO has the value 'Y' for the property studyRefActive ?

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ArgumentCaptor. Let me elaborate below:

```
RegDao mockRegDao = mock(RegDao.class);
RegService regService = new RegService(mockRegDao);
Study study = new Study();
//I think you can remove the line below. Please test it on your implementation.
Mockito.doNothing.when(mockRegDao).saveStudy(any(Study.class)); 

regService.saveData(study);

ArgumentCaptor<Study> studyArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Study.class);
Mockito.verify(mockRegDao).save(studyArgumentCaptor.capture());

//here you are going to retrieve the value that was sent as a parameter to the method "save" of RegDao class.
Study savedStudy = studyArgumentCaptor.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for idea.But i was getting some error "Wanted but not invoked"

Comment: is it because my mockRegDao extends abstract class which has save method ?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you share the complete code of all classes involved?